# VS Code hangs (forever) when connecting to Python Virtual Enviornment for Jupyter interactive

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have VSC 1.71.2 on Windows.  When trying to use an interactive python session, it just hangs at the Connecting to kernel step.  There are no error messages.  I've tried multiple virtual environments and they all do the same (which is nothing).  I don't know what I may have done since the last time it's worked until now.  I can still activate the Venvs in a terminal.

I'm not really sure what else to try or check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update the `pyzmq` package:

```
conda update pyzmq
conda update ipykernel
```